# Excel Alert Prompt

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel-web-access-webpart, alert

**Hey Guys!**

I was wondering if I can set an alert in an excel document that publishes weekly for a certain individual in SharePoint? Showing what was updated, by who and etc...or no.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select the document by clicking on the checkmark column, clicking on "Files" in the upper-left corner, then selecting "Alert Me" - "Set alert on this document".  From there you can select who wants to be notified, alert types, and when to send the alert.